# Vb.net/Mysql throws fatal error when @variable is added to mysql query

Tags: mysql, vb.net, fatal-error

Hi I'm using the following query/code to fill the datagrid

```
Private Sub btnSave_frmCreateInvoice_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave_frmCreateInvoice.Click
 Dim qryGetInvoiceItems as string = "select  @s:=@s+1 'SLNO', ini_item_details 'Item Description', ini_item_quantity 'Quantity', ini_item_rate 'Rate', round(ini_item_quantity*ini_item_rate,2) 'Item Amount' from tbl_invoice_items, (SELECT @s:=0) AS s where ini_invoice_no=" & txtInvoiceNumber_frmCreateInvoice.Text & " and ini_status=1 order by ini_id ASC"
 fill_datagrid(dgInvoiceItems_frmCreateInvoice, qryGetInvoiceItems)
 End Sub

Public Sub fill_datagrid(ByVal datagrid As DataGridView, ByVal query As String)
    Using conn As New MySqlConnection
        Try
            conn.ConnectionString = constr
            conn.Open()
            Dim sqlcommand As New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
            Dim sqlDataAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            Dim bSource As New BindingSource
            sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = sqlcommand
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dt)
            bSource.DataSource = dt
            datagrid.DataSource = bSource
            sqlDataAdapter.Dispose()
        Finally
            If conn IsNot Nothing Then
                conn.Dispose()
            End If
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
```

In mysql query, i'm using @s to get SLNO for each item. The query is running perfectly as desired in MYSQL Console but it is throwing fatal error when run in the application

```
An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Additional information: Fatal error encountered during command execution.
```

If I remove `@s:=@s+1` and `(SELECT @s:=0) AS s`, then the application works fine.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to form the SQL query, but there is another step required.  Using this SQL:

```vb
Dim SQL = "SET @s=0; SELECT Id, Name, Description, A, B, C, D, @s:=@s+1 As SLNO FROM Alpha"
Using dbcon As New MySqlConnection(MySQLConnStr)
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(SQL, dbcon)

        dbcon.Open()
        dtSample = New DataTable

        dtSample.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
End Using
dgv2.DataSource = dtSample
```

Note that you do not need a `DataAdapter` just to fill a `DataTable`; there are meant for a bit more heavy lifting than that.  This SQL also works:

```vb
Dim SQL = <sql>
        SELECT Id, Name, Description, A, B, C, D, @s:=@s+1 As SLNO 
            FROM Alpha, (SELECT @s :=0) ss
      </sql>.Value
```

The XML literal is just to eliminate scroll.  The `(SELECT @s :=0) ss` portion acts as inline initialization and does the same as the separate statement in the first ( `SET @s=0;` ).

#### This is the trick

By default, MySQL does not allow user variables ( `@s` ), so you have to enable them to avoid the fatal error exception.  If you `View Detail` you should see *{"Parameter '@s' must be defined."}*.  User vars are enabled via the connection string:

```vb
"allowuservariables=True;server=...;database=xxx;user id=uuu;password=pppp;port=3306"
```

MySQL allows for a [large number of options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html) you can enable as needed in the connection string.  If you use more than one or two you may want to use `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` to create it to avoid formatting errors.

Once user variables are enabled, the results are the same with either SQL (MySQL 6.9.8.0):

[image]

Comment: Thanks Plutonix, for your time and detailed explanation.. You saved my work,

I just added this part to the connection string : `allowuservariables=True;` and it's awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your query to look like

```
select  ini_item_details as 'Item Description', 
ini_item_quantity as 'Quantity', 
ini_item_rate as 'Rate', 
round(ini_item_quantity*ini_item_rate,2) as 'Item Amount',
@rownum := @rownum + 1 as 'SLNO' 
from tbl_invoice_items, 
(SELECT @rownum := 0) s 
where ini_invoice_no=" & txtInvoiceNumber_frmCreateInvoice.Text & " 
and ini_status=1 
order by ini_id;
```